# How to composite functions and persist the progress

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, swift2, persistence

I have a sequence of asynchronous methods defined like so:

```
func step1(input: Step1InputData, completion: (Step1OutputData -> Void)) { /* do something */ }
func step2(input: Step1OutputData, completion: (Step2OutputData -> Void)) { /* do something */ }
// etc...
```

As you can see, the output of `step1` is the input of `step2`. These types all implement the `StepData` protocol:

```
protocol StepData {}
class Step1InputData : StepData { }
class Step1OutputData : StepData { }
class Step2OutputData : StepData { }
```

Finally, I have this custom operator:

```
infix operator => { associativity left }

func => <P:StepData, Q:StepData, R:StepData> (left:((P, Q -> Void) -> Void), right:((Q, R -> Void) -> Void)) -> ((P, R -> Void) -> Void) {
    return { (x, completion) in
        left(x, { y in
            right(y, completion)
        })
    }
}
```

... which means I can write the following:

```
let combinedStep = step1 => step2
```

Which is great because it's super readable, and *crucially* it enforces type safety between the steps.

The problem is that I want to be able to persist the progress of a `combinedStep`. For example, `step1` could be an image upload and `step2` could be a local storage write. If `step2` fails, the next time I try, I want to pick up where I left off, rather than re-uploading the image. Of course, there could be any number of steps chained together.

I *could* come up with a system that has an array of steps and manages the passing of data between steps and would be able to persist the progress, however, I can't think of a way to do this while still keeping the compile-time type safety.

Can someone with more experience of functional programming point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the specific question I asked here, in case it is useful to anyone else turned out to be to take a similar approach to [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Strictly speaking, it is caching, rather than memoization, but the concept of wrapping the step function in another function that takes a cache key parameter is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into frameworks like [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org), [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures), and [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa).

Those framework are in the same problem and solution space as you, asynchronous operations that need to be composed, and they all provide multiple ways to handle errors and retries.

If you like any of those you could adopt them in place of your custom implementation, and leverage the support of a big community of developers. Or you could just find inspiration from their code to bring back in your.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your operator right associative and pass an enum in the completion handler to allow for failure.

```
enum StepResult<Output> {
    case Success(Output)
    case Failure((StepResult<Output>->Void)->Void)

    static func toFailHandlerWithInput<Input>(input: Input, processor: (Input,(StepResult<Output>)->Void)->Void) -> StepResult<Output> {
        let handler : ((StepResult<Output>->Void)->Void) = { completion in
            processor(input) { pout in
                completion(pout)
            }
        }
        return .Failure(handler)
    }
}


infix operator => { associativity right }

func =><Input,Intermediate,Output>(left: (Input,(StepResult<Intermediate>)->Void)->Void, right: (Intermediate,(StepResult<Output>)->Void)->Void) -> (Input,(StepResult<Output>)->Void)->Void {
    var mergedOp : ((Input,(StepResult<Output>)->Void)->Void)!

    mergedOp = { input,completion in
        left(input) { intermediate in
            switch intermediate {
            case .Success(let output):
                right(output, completion)
            case .Failure:
                let failure = StepResult.toFailHandlerWithInput(input, processor: mergedOp)
                completion(failure)
            }
        }
    }
    return mergedOp
}


var counter1 = 0
func step1(input: Int, completion: (StepResult<Double>)->Void) {
    print("performing step 1...")
    counter1 += 1
    if ( counter1 > 1 ) {
        print("Step 1 will succeed...")
        let result = 2.0 * Double(input + counter1)
        completion(.Success(result))
    } else {
        print("Step 1 fails...")
        completion(StepResult.toFailHandlerWithInput(input, processor: step1))
    }
}


var counter2 = 0
func step2(input: Double, completion: (StepResult<Double>)->Void) {
    print("performing Step 2...")
    counter2 += 1
    if ( counter2 > 2 ) {
        print("Step 2 will succeed...")
        let result = 3 * input + Double(counter2)
        completion(.Success(result))
    } else {
        print("Step 2 fails...")
        completion(StepResult.toFailHandlerWithInput(input, processor: step2))
    }
}


var counter3 = 0
func step3(input: Double, completion: (StepResult<Double>)->Void) {
    print("performing Step 3...")
    counter3 += 1
    if ( counter3 > 1 ) {
        print("Step 3 will succeed...")
        let result = 4 * input + Double(counter3)
        completion(.Success(result))
    } else {
        print("Step 3 fails...")
        completion(StepResult.toFailHandlerWithInput(input, processor: step3))
    }
}


func comboHandler(result: StepResult<Double>) {
    switch result {
    case .Success(let output):
        print("output: \(output)")
    case .Failure(let failHandler):
        failHandler(comboHandler)   // call again until success
    }
}


let combinedSteps = step1 => step2 => step3
combinedSteps(5) { result in
    comboHandler(result)
}
```